# How can I add a 'read more' button below each article?

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a project in college, using MySQL and PHP. Here is my code for getting data from the database:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO articles (artical,article_heding,date,categories ) VALUES ('$artical','$heading','$datetime','$categories')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);

$sql3="select * from articles";
$rs2=mysql_query($sql3);
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
{
$rating=$row2['article_heding'];
$artical=$row2['artical'];

echo $row2['article_heding']."<br>".substr($row2['artical'], 0,10)."<br><br>";}}
```

Currently I am just showing a summary of each article (`substr($row2['artical'], 0,10)`), but I would like to put a read more button under each article to show the full text. How can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you will need Javascript to do this. Are you looking to expand the text to the full version when the user clicks "Read More"?

Comment: @ Brendan Bullen yes! i need to expand this to full version! can you help with this?

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZxQZ/) to illustrate this, oddly enough. It does use jQuery, but that is easy enough to include.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You are also welcome to use the "$" command instead of "jQuery". I wrote it using "jQuery" because of specific requirements not pertaining to your situation (probably).

Also not that the "more" text in my example will always be hidden if the user has javascript disabled. To fix this remove the .css and add:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#more").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know (since this is handled client-side (you don' wanna reload the page right?)) you have to use javascript to do this as php is pure server-based

Comment: thz... how can i do this using java? i am save this page as ***.php can do this? and i need to reload it to! can i?

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to reload the page, you defenitely need JavaScript, respecitvely a JS Framework.

Here is what you can achieve with **jQuery** and a **Plugin**: [jQuery Expander Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/index.html#getting-started)

and here: [Quick and Easy jQuery Read More Script Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/5368/quick-and-easy-jquery-read-more-script-tutorial)

also, someone else has already asked a similar question: [Read More Feature with JQuery slideToggle Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249804/read-more-feature-with-jquery-slidetoggle-method)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found answer to this!! Here it is : First I add these lines in next echo line:

```
echo "<form action='welcome.php' method='get'>
       <input name='".$articalid."' type='submit' value='Read More' />
       <input name='buttonId' type='hidden' value='".$articalid."' />
       <input name='buttonIdd' type='hidden' value='".$rating."' />
      </form>";
```

After that i made "welcome.php" file look like this:

```
$artical=$_REQUEST['buttonId'];
$heading=$_REQUEST['buttonIdd'];    
echo $heading."</br></br>";

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM articles where id='$artical'";  
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL); 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
echo $row['artical'];
}
```

Done!!! it Works!!!